# Regular Expression to replace multiple hyphens with a single one

Tags: java, regex, coldfusion

I wrote a Regular Expression that generates a url like

```
/abc/deutschland/bbs-tagesfahrten/betz-mode-frotier-center-–-tress-teigwaren.html.
```

Now I want to replace the repeating dashes with a single one. How can I?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
String.replaceAll("--+", "-");
```

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps simpler that any of the suggestions would be:

```
s/-{2,}/-/g
```

Comment: to CF-ize tO's suggestion:

<cfset cleanURL = reReplace(InputURL,"-{2,}","-","all")>

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
s/---*/-/g
```

Comment: This will also replace "-" with "-". Harmless, but unnecessary.

Comment: @lutz Another solution is `s/--+*/-/g`

Comment: @Gaim: You sure you want that asterisk in there? ;)

Answer (score 1):

To replace *any* repeated dashes in the whole URL:

```
<cfset InputUrl = "/abc/deutschland/bbs-tagesfahrten/betz-mode-frotier-center-–-tress-teigwaren.html">
<cfset CleanUrl = REReplace(InputUrl, "-+", "-", "ALL")>
```

To work on the file part only:

```
<cfset PathPart = REReplace(InputUrl, "(.*/).*", "\1")>
<cfset FilePart = ListLast(InputUrl, "/")>
<cfset CleanUrl = PathPart & REReplace(FilePart, "-+", "-", "ALL")>
```